# $.mobile.activePage is undefined

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

```
$.mobile.activePage is undefined
```

Does anybody have a fix for this?

It is being used like this.

```
if ($.mobile.activePage.data("iscroll") == "enable") {
    fixed($.mobile.activePage);
}
```

This is right after this and this works.

```
$('a.numContact').live("click", function(e) {  
    e.preventDefault();
    var dataurl = $(this).attr("data-url");  
    if (dataurl != null)  
    $.mobile.changePage("loadMobis.php",{
            data:dataurl
    });   
});
```

Is this a bug?

Comment: any errors in the debug console? Also in the docs I didn't see the data chaining option: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/methods.html (bottom of the page)

Answer (score 3):

changing the line (99) ...

```
if ($.mobile.activePage.data("iscroll") == "enable") {
```

to...

```
if (($.mobile.activePage) && ($.mobile.activePage.data("iscroll") == "enable")) {
```

seems to solve the problem